# How to do streaming with .pls files in android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming

I want to play a .pls file for my android application using  this url `http://playerservices.streamtheworld.com/pls/VIRGINRADIO_DUBAIAAC.pls`
 I know that it is not possible to  play .pls files using MediaPlayer directly.So I parsed this file using a Pls parser  and  set each url to a media player.But it won't work .Also shows the error `error (1, -2147483648)`.

```
public class PlayListParser {

    private BufferedReader reader;

    public PlayListParser(String url) {
        try {
            URL plsFileUrl = new URL(url.trim());
            URLConnection urlConnection = plsFileUrl.openConnection();
           // InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.openStream());
            InputStream iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            this.reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
            // this.reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file), 1024);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("PlayListParser", "Got MalformedURLException  = " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PlayListParser", "Got  IOException = " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public List<String> getUrls() {
        LinkedList<String> urls = new LinkedList<String>();
        while (true) {
            try {
                String line = reader.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                    break;
                }
                String url = parseLine(line);
                if (url != null && !url.equals("")) {
                    urls.add(url);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return urls;
    }

    private String parseLine(String line) {
        if (line == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String trimmed = line.trim();
        if (trimmed.indexOf("http") >= 0) {
            return trimmed.substring(trimmed.indexOf("http"));
        }
        return "";
    }
}


PlayListParser playListParser = new PlayListParser(URL_PLS_STREAMING);
List<String > playList = playListParser.getUrls();
if(playList != null && ! playList.isEmpty()){
    for(String url : playList){
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(playList.get(0));//"http://stream2.streamq.net:8020/");
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();

            }
        });
        //mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.e("MainActivity","Got IllegalArgumentException = " + e.getMessage());

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e("MainActivity","Got IllegalStateException = " + e.getMessage());

        } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("MainActivity","Got IOException = " + e.getMessage());

        }
    }
}
```

How can i play this .pls file? I could not find a good reference about it.Also i want to play,pause,and rewind these files.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Show the code for how you process the pls file.

Answer (score 7):

### Get URL from .pls file

This will return URL like http://stream2.streamq.net:8020

```java
package com.direct.radio.global;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

public class GetStreamingUrl {

private static String LOGTAG = "GetStreamingUrl";
private Context mContext;

public GetStreamingUrl(Context context) {
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "call to constructor");
    this.mContext = context;

}

public LinkedList<String> getStreamingUrl(String url) {

    Log.i(LOGTAG, "get streaming url");
    final BufferedReader br;
    String murl = null;
    LinkedList<String> murls = null;
    try {
        URLConnection mUrl = new URL(url).openConnection();
        br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(mUrl.getInputStream()));
        murls = new LinkedList<String>();
        while (true) {
            try {
                String line = br.readLine();

                if (line == null) {
                    break;
                }
                murl = parseLine(line);
                if (murl != null && !murl.equals("")) {
                    murls.add(murl);

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "url to stream :" + murl);
    return murls;
}

private String parseLine(String line) {
    if (line == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String trimmed = line.trim();
    if (trimmed.indexOf("http") >= 0) {
        return trimmed.substring(trimmed.indexOf("http"));
    }
    return "";
        }
  }
```

### Activity_Player.java or Service_Player.java

you can write this code as per your need , Define this method

```java
LinkedList<String> urls;

private LinkedList<String> fGetPlayableUrl(String mPls) {
    GetStreamingUrl oGetStreamingUrl = new GetStreamingUrl(Activity_Splash.this);
    urls = oGetStreamingUrl.getStreamingUrl(mPls);
    return urls;
}
```

Here, `fGetPlayableUrl(String mPls)` pass `.pls` URL. Now you have streaming URL.

```java
MediaPlayer  mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

Now, pass URL to

```java
mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(urls.toString());
mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("") ,here the url is url of pls file or url from parsed pls file?

Comment: Here direct you have to pass URL that you received from `fGetPlayableUrl()`

Comment: That means url from parsed pls file like in my code.But it does not work for me.Shows exception SntpClient : request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Comment: did you given `Internet` permission ?

Comment: @DevuSoman : `SntpClient : request time failed:` - SNTP is Simple Network Time Protocol - this has nothing to do with any of your code.

Comment: @Devu Soman, have you implemented this .pls task? i am looking for same solution but not found yet. Please help.

Comment: @Geettaunk what is problem ?

Comment: @Ann I have tested this code where i didn't found any error

Comment: @Rstar i have get a .pls file from xml into a listview and i move that listview to another activity but i dont know how to Get URL from .pls file can u say little bit clear plz?

Comment: @SudiptaSom Good to hear.