# How to develop a live streaming radio application in android from a given web proxy

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, ioexception

I am developing a live streaming radio application in android, I have a link which contain a .pls file,  on clicking the link it will be downloaded as a .pls file .I want to play the music stream live from a web proxy to my android application.The server is 24X7 running .I have tried some codings but I am getting some error , Can anybody help me here..

giving my logcat below

```
01-31 01:33:43.209: E/MediaPlayer(1216): error (1, -2147483648)

01-31 01:33:43.309: E/MediaPlayer(1216): Error (1,-2147483648)

01-31 01:33:45.549: I/Choreographer(1216): Skipped 252 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

01-31 01:33:45.699: I/Choreographer(1216): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Java Class :

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private ProgressBar playSeekBar;

    private Button buttonPlay;

    private Button buttonStopPlay;

    private MediaPlayer player;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeUIElements();

        try {
            initializeMediaPlayer();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void initializeUIElements() {

        playSeekBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        playSeekBar.setMax(100);
        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

        buttonStopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
        buttonStopPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonPlay) {
            startPlaying();
        } else if (v == buttonStopPlay) {
            stopPlaying();
        }
    }

    private void startPlaying() {
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(true);
        buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);

        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        player.prepareAsync();

        player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                player.start();
            }
        });

    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        if (player.isPlaying()) {
            player.stop();
            player.release();
            try {
                initializeMediaPlayer();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
        buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
        playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    private void initializeMediaPlayer() throws IOException {
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
          player.setDataSource("//.pls file link");
        //
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
                Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (player.isPlaying()) {
            player.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

I am unsure but this *may* be the cause of your problem:

```
player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                player.start();
            }
        });
```

You are setting the listener multiple times for the player; each time you click the button. This should be in `onCreate()`

Comment: :Buddy  Thanks for the answer , I have tried one link and it is working but it is not with the .pls file link which I want to be be used for my application. Is there any parsing mechanism needed ?

Comment: @user3064450 Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931555/how-to-do-streaming-with-pls-files-in-android **and** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277143/parse-and-play-a-pls-file-in-android